# Unity 5 - Unity Editor Facebook Login unresponsive size

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk, responsiveness

I'm a newbie start making my game on Unity. Current stage is testing with Facebook and make a leader board from it.
Currently I'm using **Unity 5.1.1f1 Personal Edition** and **Facebook SDK 7.0.2 beta** because SDK 6.2.2 doesn't work with Unity 5.1.

I've watched this guy's tutorial ([youtube's link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmeMHY5D4SI&list=LLJZyYxbpIjwsjTFrMJlWg-w&index=2)) on how to integrate Facebook SDK with Unity. The Facebook login panel is very weird on my game screen (My game is made for iPhone portrait orientation). Below is the link to the screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78qdh.png

You can see the Box is not responsive with screen size. If I didn't set game screen to "Maximize On Play" I can't press the "Login" button. I tried to find how to change its size or design but I've found none.

The second problem is I have tried build this project and deploy on my iPhone with iOS 8.4. Every time I press "Facebook Login" button, nothing came up and the app crashed.

I don't know this is beta problem or what but it's kinda basic function of this SDK.. just login and it's not functional as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Legacy UI which you are seeing in Unity Editor has nothing to do with IOS  build. your App will redirect to Facebook page/App for Login Authentication. So in editor you can just set game view to free aspects from top left and use login controls by resizing your game view. and regarding other issue please provide code which you are using for Login button. and try to log to know why is your game crashing.

Comment: Thank you very much. : )
I have tried messing around with the code and now it's worked! The problem is I used loginWithPublishPermission() instead of loginWithReadPermission().